# Anchor scrolling position is wrong because of dynamic content

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, next.js

I have an element with the `#pro-plan` id.

When I go to `localhost:3000/#pro-plan`, the page scrolls to the section properly; however, sometimes it scrolls to the wrong position.

What I'm thinking is that there are some elements that load lazily, so the heights of some elements change over time. Maybe, while the page is being scrolled, the heights change, causing the calculated position to be incorrect.

What I tried was changing the attribute from `id` to `data-name`. When my page is mounted, I retrieve the `location.hash` value and then use the `scrollIntoView` function in a `setTimeout` callback with a 500ms delay, which I believe is not a good solution.

I couldn't find any way to solve this. Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues. I didn't find the best solution but I managed to write this function to scroll to the element repeatedly until it was visible. You can change the count and interval as per your needs.

```js
const repeatedScroll = () => {
  let scrollToElement = document.getElementById("pro-plan");

  if (!scrollToElement) return;
  let count = 0;
  let timer = setInterval(() => {
    scrollToElement = document.getElementById("pro-plan");
    scrollToElement.scrollIntoView({
      behavior: "smooth",
      block: "start"
    });
    if (count === 5) { // you can change this according to your usecase
      clearInterval(timer);
    }

    // you can check if its scrolled to the element and cancel the interval
  }, 400) // change as per your requirement
}
```